# Problems reading CSV in Octave

Tags: matlab, csv, octave

I have a .csv file and I can't read it on Octave. On R I just use the command below and everything is read alright:

```
myData <- read.csv("myData.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

However, when I go to Octave it doesn't do it properly with the below command:

```
myData = csvread('myData.csv',1,0);
```

When I open the file with Notepad, the data looks something like the below. Note there isn't a comma separating the last column name (i.e. Column3) from the first value (i.e. Value1) and the same thing happens with the last value of the first row (i.e. Value3) and the first value of the second row (i.e Value4)

```
Column1,Column2,Column3Value1,Value2,Value3Value4,Value5,Value6
```

The Column1 is meant for date values (with format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss), I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: csvread only reads numeric data. As a fellow `R` user I feel your pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csvread` only reads numeric data, so a date does not qualify unfortunately.

In Octave you might want to check out the [dataframe](http://wiki.octave.org/Dataframe_package) package. In Matlab you would do `readtable`.

Otherwise there are also more primitive functions you can use like `textscan`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, was going crazy with this...!

Answer (score 5):

Alex's answers already explains why `csvread` does not work for your case. That function only reads numeric data and returns an array. Since your fields are all strings, you need something that reads a csv file into a cell array.

That function is named [`csv2cell`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/io/function/csv2cell.html) and is part of the [io package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/io/index.html).

As a separate note, if you plan to make operation with those dates, you may want to convert those dates as strings, into serial date numbers. This will allow you to put your dates in a numeric array which will allow for faster operations and reduced memory usage. Also, the `financial` package has many functions to deal with dates.